# Activating the cluster in Apache Ignite

Tags: security, authentication, cluster-computing, ignite

I am using Apache Ignite 2.8.0. When persistence is enabled then my server becomes Inactive. When I am trying to activate the cluster (only one server) by `control.bat --activate`, it asks username and password, but when I activate using code `ignite.cluster().active(true);` it doesn't ask.

I need an explanation why it doesn't ask username and password when I activating the cluster by code?

Answer (score 1):

You can only do that from a node that's already a part of topology (obviously) and thus passed security checks.

Apache Ignite only has thin client authentication currently. If you're looking for server-server authentication, use SSL or check [GridGain security plugin](https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/administrators-guide/security/authentication).

Comment: i am able to activate by Client node.. my Client node doesn't need authentication.  is my client node automatically become a part of the topology?

Comment: Yes, a client node is a part of cluster topology.